# Get latitude and longitude of a geography column

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type

When doing the query in postgres to one that has a column whose data type is geography(MultiLineString, 4326) throws me the following result:

```
select geom from base.osm_roads_free_1 limit 100;
"0105000020E610000001000000010200000002000000ACFE08C380585EC04B598638D6FD44409A93179980585EC0A48D23D6E2FD4440"
```

I applied the ST_AsText (geom) function and it gives me the following result:

```
"MULTILINESTRING((-121.382859 41.9831,-121.382849 41.983485))"
```

My intention is to get into different columns longitude and latitude, example:

```
LON   LAT
-120.41651 40.192448
-120.416214 40.192471
-120.416055 40.192489
-120.415904 40.192524
-120.415767 40.192549
-120.415651 40.192559
-120.41553  40.192563
-120.415375 40.192546
-120.415246 40.192526
-120.415097 40.192528
-120.414956 40.192539
```

Comment: It helps if you *think* "longitude, latitude", because you will then be looking at coordinates in X,Y order.

Comment: What you have is the lon/lat data in decimal degrees.  You are querying a linestring which explains why you have the lon/lat of two different nodes on the line.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  It appears your result has already given your the coordinates (`-121.382859 41.9831, -121.382849 41.983485`) - what about this isn't what you were after?

Comment: You might find ST_X and ST_Y useful too, rather than ST_AsText.

Comment: If I already have the latitude and longitude data but grouped it as follows: MULTILINESTRING ((- 121.382859 41.9831, -121.382849 41.983485))
My intention is to obtain this data individually

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: @LizandroLuzonM there is an **[edit]** link below your question which you can click on to edit your question to clarify the problem and add more information.  Please don't add your extra info as comments, as it makes it difficult to understand the full problem.

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope to be more explicit.

Comment: You still have a vertex order issue.  There are no values south of 90 degrees.

Answer (score 11):

This is what [`ST_DumpPoints`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) is for:

```sql
SELECT ST_X((dp).geom) AS lon, ST_Y((dp).geom) AS lat
FROM (
    SELECT ST_DumpPoints(
        ST_GeogFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-121.382859 41.9831,-121.382849 41.983485))')::geometry
    ) AS dp
) AS foo;
```

Output:

```
"lon";"lat"
-121.382859;41.9831
-121.382849;41.983485
```

Comment: OP is using `geography` -- `ST_DumpPoints()` parameter needs to be casted to `geometry`

Comment: True. So that's just an additional `::geometry` cast: `ST_DumpPoints(my_geography_column::geometry)`.

Comment: Do you want me to tidy up with a `GeogFromText` and a cast?

Comment: Go right ahead.

Comment: Also try experimenting with `ST_AsLatLonText((dp).geom)` to show a human readable latitude, longitude.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Listing the coordinates in the "reverse order" (Y, X), helps me:

```
lat        lon
40.192448 -120.41651
40.192471 -120.416214
40.192489 -120.416055
40.192524 -120.415904
40.192549 -120.415767
40.192559 -120.415651
40.192563 -120.41553
40.192546 -120.415375
40.192526 -120.415246
40.192528 -120.415097
40.192539 -120.414956
```

ref.: http://maptools.com/tutorials/lat_lon/definitions

[image: lat] Latitude

[image: lon] Longitude

As mentioned above, you can also use the following:

```
SELECT (ST_AsLatLonText('POINT (-120.41651 40.192448)'));
    st_aslatlontext
----------------------------
40°11'32.8"N 120°24'559.4"W
```